# capture multi-line text

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I've a html document..:

```
<p>blah blah<p>
<p>blah blah
<br>blah blah</p>
<p>blah blah
<br>
    <br>
blah blah</p>
```

And I want to remove double-breaking spaces. (can be found in last paragraph)

I tried this expression, but it will remove anything between first `<br>` and second `<br>`.
But I want to remove just last `<br>` (which comes right after another `<br>`, in next line):

```
/<br>(.*?)<br>/s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<br>((\s*)<br>)+
```

It will match (on your example) two or more `<br>` tags that have some sort of space between them.